# Excel formula to multiply a value by 1000 if between -10 and 10

Tags: excel

I want a formula for and excel spreadsheet that multiplies values by 1000 if between -10 and 10 and multiplies them by 1 if not between -10 and 10.

I have tried this:

```
=IF(A2>-10,A2*1000,IF(A2<-10,A2*1))
```

The problem is for positive values it multiplies the values by 1000 which I don't want except between 0-10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=IF(AND(A2 > -10, A2 < 10), A2*1000, A2)`

The `AND` operator allows you to enter multiple boolean conditions to an if statement and can be easier to read than nested `IF` statements.

Comment: Hi @UserName121 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need.
Check one condition, if it's true, check the other condition. In you case you've just checked one condition by the time you print A2*1000.

`=IF(A2 > -10,IF(A2<10,A2*1000,A2),A2)`

Answer (score 0):

IF(AND(A1>-10,A1<10),A1*1000,A1)